# How do you check in which module a function is defined? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check to which module a function belongs?
Like,

```
check_module(sqrt)
```

Would return `math` and so on, if at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions have a `__module__` attribute:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt.__module__
'math'
```

You can use the [`inspect.getmodule()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) to get the actual module object for a given object:

```
>>> from inspect import getmodule
>>> getmodule(sqrt)
<module 'math' from '/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/python-3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/math.so'>
```

`inspect.getmodule()` works for more than just functions and classes; it'll go through some length to find a module for a given object, based on the metadata on that object.

Comment: For me (`Python 2.7.3`)
`>>> getmodule(math.sqrt)` returns
`<module 'math' (built-in)>`

Comment: @g4ur4v: `math` is a C-extension module, and it can either be compiled as a dynamically loaded library or made part of the Python binary itself. It looks like yours is compiled into the Python binary. `built-in` just means: no separate filename.

Comment: @g4ur4v getmodule(math.sqrt) assumes you know the module 'math' already, not the case here.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari: even so, the result would not be any different; and just echoing `math` would also give the same output of course.

Comment: It's usually better to avoid "from" imports - this eliminates the problem.

Comment: @user1277476: using `from` is usually *just fine*, depending on the context. Usually you don't need the module anyway.

Comment: `from m import x` is not a problem when imports are at the top of the module, as recommended by PEP 8.