# How to log successful starting and finishing of a function execution?

Tags: python-2.7

I am debugging a code. I have a code with many lines in python 2. And some functions are executed long. To check a function completed successfully I am doing the following ugly stuff:

```
print("creating an object... "), # a comma here to print a subsequent print in one line 
obj = TimeDemandingFunction()
print("end")
```

Is there a best method for logging?

P.S.
the function `TimeDemandingFunction()` is from an **external library**.

Comment: How about https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html?

Comment: Is there any better method with minimum interference?

Comment: How I understood, I need to go into the function definition and add logging stuff. It is not the case. I would like to add something like a decorator to the **my_var = foo()**, where the info about starting and finishing will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baduker's answer prompted me to give a modified version of his answer. I will summarize and give several examples.
Construction of a decorator is similar as Baduker, but several modifications: (1) there is a notification that a function has been started with the information where it was called (number of line and which keys are used), (2) it writes info about time only at the end. Below I give examples how to use it for external functions:

```
import functools
import timeit
import sys

def my_custom_timer(func):
@functools.wraps(func)
def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    s = ''
    for arg_name in kwargs:
            s += arg_name + '; line=' + str(sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno)
    print("Started {!r}({!r}) ".format(func.__name__, s)),
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
    end_time = timeit.default_timer()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Finished in {:.4f} seconds.".format(run_time))
    return value
return wrapper_timer
```

Then goes an interesting part. First, you need to find out the whole path to the function. Use the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076368/how-do-you-check-in-which-module-a-function-is-defined-python). Briefly, functions have a **module** attribute:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt.__module__
'math'
```

First, let's redefine the `sqrt` function from some module:

```
import math
@my_custom_timer
def sqrt(*args, **kwargs):
    return math.sqrt(*args, **kwargs)
```

What if a function from a built-in module?! No problem. The answer is `__builtin__` module:

```
>>> print(divmod.__module__)
'__builtin__'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all you need is a decorator to, say, log function's execution time you could use something like this:

```
import functools
import time


def my_custom_timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Finished {func.__name__!r} in {run_time:.4f} seconds.")
        return value
    return wrapper_timer


@my_custom_timer
def waste_some_time(num_times):
    for _ in range(num_times):
        sum([i**2 for i in range(10000)])


waste_some_time(2)
```

Output:

```
Finished 'waste_some_time' in 0.0050 seconds.
```

EDIT:
Here's how you would decorate a function from another module. First, you have to import it and then put it in a function block.

```
@my_custom_timer
def find_evens(n):
    return itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2, range(n))


evens = find_evens(20)
print(list(evens))
```

Output:

```
Finished 'find_evens' in 0.0000 seconds.
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Note that by definition, a decorator is a function that takes another function and extends the behavior of the latter function without explicitly modifying it.

And if you want to use the decorator in another module of yours, just import it as if you would import any other function.

```
from othermodule import your_decorator

@your_decorator
def some_function():
    pass
```

Comment: Baduker, thank you! But what if the function waste_some_time(num_times) is from an external library, and I don't have direct access? 
If a function inside of an external library, I can't put the decorator my_custom_timer under the function. How to deal with it?

Comment: Well, you decorate a function in *your* code. If you use a function or method from an external module then you still can decorate it as long as you put it in a function block. See the updated answer.